Eliminating shift/reduce conflict in bison parser
I am working on defining a bison grammar for http and am dealing with a number of shift/reduce conflicts with regards to how optional whitespace is handled at the end of the header field value. Here is a simplified version of the grammar that just deals with the header field portion:
%{
  #define YYDEBUG 1
  int yylex(void);
  void yyerror(char *s);
%}
%token X00
%%
/* Reference - RFC 7230 */

headerField : fieldName ':' OWS fieldValue OWS CRLF | fieldName ':' OWS CRLF ;

fieldValue : fieldValueSS | fieldValue fieldValueSS ;

fieldValueSS : fieldContent | obsFold ; 

fieldContent : fieldVChar optFieldContent ;

optFieldContent : /* empty */ | RWS fieldVChar ;

fieldVChar : obsText | VCHAR ;

/* Even though this line fold is obsolete still account for it for consistency with the RFC */
obsFold : CRLF RWS ;

fieldName : token ;

token : tChar | token tChar ;

tChar : '!' | '#' | '$' | '%' | '&' | '\x27' | '*' | '+' | '-' | '.' | '^' | '_' | '`' | '|' | '~' | DIGIT | ALPHA ;

obsText :     r__1 ;

/* Tokens */
ALPHA : LOALPHA | UPALPHA ;

LOALPHA :     r__2 ;

UPALPHA :     r__3 ;

DIGIT :     r__4 ;

SP : '\x20' ;

HTAB : '\x09' ;

WS : SP | HTAB ;

OWS : /* empty */ | OWS WS ;

RWS : WS | RWS WS ;

VCHAR :     r__5 ;

LF : '\x0a' ;

CR : '\x0d' ;

CRLF : CR LF ;

/* Range Expansions */
r__1 : 
  '\x80' | '\x81' | '\x82' | '\x83' | '\x84' | '\x85' | '\x86' | '\x87' | 
  '\x88' | '\x89' | '\x8a' | '\x8b' | '\x8c' | '\x8d' | '\x8e' | '\x8f' | 
  '\x90' | '\x91' | '\x92' | '\x93' | '\x94' | '\x95' | '\x96' | '\x97' | 
  '\x98' | '\x99' | '\x9a' | '\x9b' | '\x9c' | '\x9d' | '\x9e' | '\x9f' | 
  '\xa0' | '\xa1' | '\xa2' | '\xa3' | '\xa4' | '\xa5' | '\xa6' | '\xa7' | 
  '\xa8' | '\xa9' | '\xaa' | '\xab' | '\xac' | '\xad' | '\xae' | '\xaf' | 
  '\xb0' | '\xb1' | '\xb2' | '\xb3' | '\xb4' | '\xb5' | '\xb6' | '\xb7' | 
  '\xb8' | '\xb9' | '\xba' | '\xbb' | '\xbc' | '\xbd' | '\xbe' | '\xbf' | 
  '\xc0' | '\xc1' | '\xc2' | '\xc3' | '\xc4' | '\xc5' | '\xc6' | '\xc7' | 
  '\xc8' | '\xc9' | '\xca' | '\xcb' | '\xcc' | '\xcd' | '\xce' | '\xcf' | 
  '\xd0' | '\xd1' | '\xd2' | '\xd3' | '\xd4' | '\xd5' | '\xd6' | '\xd7' | 
  '\xd8' | '\xd9' | '\xda' | '\xdb' | '\xdc' | '\xdd' | '\xde' | '\xdf' | 
  '\xe0' | '\xe1' | '\xe2' | '\xe3' | '\xe4' | '\xe5' | '\xe6' | '\xe7' | 
  '\xe8' | '\xe9' | '\xea' | '\xeb' | '\xec' | '\xed' | '\xee' | '\xef' | 
  '\xf0' | '\xf1' | '\xf2' | '\xf3' | '\xf4' | '\xf5' | '\xf6' | '\xf7' | 
  '\xf8' | '\xf9' | '\xfa' | '\xfb' | '\xfc' | '\xfd' | '\xfe' | '\xff' ;
r__2 : 
  '\x61' | '\x62' | '\x63' | '\x64' | '\x65' | '\x66' | '\x67' | '\x68' | 
  '\x69' | '\x6a' | '\x6b' | '\x6c' | '\x6d' | '\x6e' | '\x6f' | '\x70' | 
  '\x71' | '\x72' | '\x73' | '\x74' | '\x75' | '\x76' | '\x77' | '\x78' | 
  '\x79' | '\x7a' ;
r__3 : 
  '\x41' | '\x42' | '\x43' | '\x44' | '\x45' | '\x46' | '\x47' | '\x48' | 
  '\x49' | '\x4a' | '\x4b' | '\x4c' | '\x4d' | '\x4e' | '\x4f' | '\x50' | 
  '\x51' | '\x52' | '\x53' | '\x54' | '\x55' | '\x56' | '\x57' | '\x58' | 
  '\x59' | '\x5a' ;
r__4 : 
  '\x30' | '\x31' | '\x32' | '\x33' | '\x34' | '\x35' | '\x36' | '\x37' | 
  '\x38' | '\x39' ;
r__5 : 
  '\x21' | '\x22' | '\x23' | '\x24' | '\x25' | '\x26' | '\x27' | '\x28' | 
  '\x29' | '\x2a' | '\x2b' | '\x2c' | '\x2d' | '\x2e' | '\x2f' | '\x30' | 
  '\x31' | '\x32' | '\x33' | '\x34' | '\x35' | '\x36' | '\x37' | '\x38' | 
  '\x39' | '\x3a' | '\x3b' | '\x3c' | '\x3d' | '\x3e' | '\x3f' | '\x40' | 
  '\x41' | '\x42' | '\x43' | '\x44' | '\x45' | '\x46' | '\x47' | '\x48' | 
  '\x49' | '\x4a' | '\x4b' | '\x4c' | '\x4d' | '\x4e' | '\x4f' | '\x50' | 
  '\x51' | '\x52' | '\x53' | '\x54' | '\x55' | '\x56' | '\x57' | '\x58' | 
  '\x59' | '\x5a' | '\x5b' | '\x5c' | '\x5d' | '\x5e' | '\x5f' | '\x60' | 
  '\x61' | '\x62' | '\x63' | '\x64' | '\x65' | '\x66' | '\x67' | '\x68' | 
  '\x69' | '\x6a' | '\x6b' | '\x6c' | '\x6d' | '\x6e' | '\x6f' | '\x70' | 
  '\x71' | '\x72' | '\x73' | '\x74' | '\x75' | '\x76' | '\x77' | '\x78' | 
  '\x79' | '\x7a' | '\x7b' | '\x7c' | '\x7d' | '\x7e' ;

Looking at the .output file I can see that there are 2 conflicts in State 321:
State 321

    7 fieldContent: fieldVChar • optFieldContent

    ' '   shift, and go to state 109
    '\t'  shift, and go to state 110

    ' '       [reduce using rule 8 (optFieldContent)]
    '\t'      [reduce using rule 8 (optFieldContent)]
    $default  reduce using rule 8 (optFieldContent)

    optFieldContent  go to state 335
    SP               go to state 324
    HTAB             go to state 325
    WS               go to state 336
    RWS              go to state 337

It appears to me as though this conflict occurs when it reads in a few visible characters and then sees a whitespace. The parser does not know whether to continue accumulating characters in fieldVChar or to reduce an empty optFieldContent.
There are also 2 conflicts in State 340:
State 340                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                            
   12 obsFold: CRLF RWS •                                                                                                                                                                                   
   46 RWS: RWS • WS                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    ' '   shift, and go to state 109                                                                                                                                                                        
    '\t'  shift, and go to state 110                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    ' '       [reduce using rule 12 (obsFold)]                                                                                                                                                              
    '\t'      [reduce using rule 12 (obsFold)]                                                                                                                                                              
    $default  reduce using rule 12 (obsFold)                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    SP    go to state 324                                                                                                                                                                                   
    HTAB  go to state 325                                                                                                                                                                                   
    WS    go to state 343 

It seems as though these conflicts arise after accepting a CRLF and at least 1 whitespace token. When it receives another whitespace token it does not know whether to continue accumulating whitespace or reduce a completed obsFold rule.
I tried fixing the first of these conflicts (State 321) by disallowing an empty optFieldContent and instead incorporate it into the rule for fieldContent as follows:
fieldContent : fieldVChar | fieldVChar fieldContentSS ;

fieldContentSS : RWS fieldVChar ;

But this did not seem to do anything to resolve it.
I tried fixing the second of the conflicts (State 340) by defining a separate rule for a field value that contains an obsFold and one that does not as follows:
headerField : fieldName ':' OWS fieldValueWS CRLF | fieldName ':' OWS CRLF | fieldName ':' OWS fieldValue OWS CRLF ;

fieldValue : fieldValueSS | fieldValue fieldValueSS ;

fieldValueSS : fieldContent ; 

fieldValueWS : fieldValueSSWS | fieldValueWS fieldValueSSWS ;

fieldValueSSWS : fieldContent | obsFold ; 

And this seemed to resolve the shift/reduce conflicts, but led to a host of reduce/reduce conflicts where it did not know whether to reduce a fieldValueSSWS or a fieldValueSS upon reading in a character.

The issue resulting in reduce/reduce conflicts
The reduce/reduce conflict comes from the fact that you have the two rules:
fieldName ':' OWS fieldValueWS CRLF

and
fieldName ':' OWS fieldValue OWS CRLF

The difference between these two rules is the fourth token namely fieldValueWS and fieldValue.
They both boil down to in EBNF (Not valid Bison):
fieldValue = fieldContent+
fieldValueWS = (fieldContent | obsFold)+

The issue is that for everytime fieldContent can be matched with no obsFold. Both productions are valid, i.e. the shift-reduce parser can reduce two productions that are seemingly both valid.
In practice the bison generated parser prefers the first production that is defined, however, the parser does not know which is the correct parse as both productions are valid.
Possible fixes
To solve this you can either:

Keep it and utilize the default resolvement strategy (Not desirable)
Generalize it to only utilize the whitespace variant and add another pass to specialize it if desired.
Define a different grammar that does not have this subset that allows for multiple correct parses.

You should decide what you want to do with the reduce/reduce conflict. Either way, I hope this helps you understand why and where this reduce/reduce occurs and comes from.
